# How do you code on a Fragment in android studio

Tags: java, android

I've been trying to make a ListView appear on a fragment but one line hinders me from doing so.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
     android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, items);
```

Could anyone tell me what to do to correct my error in this line?

Comment: use getActivity() instead of "this"

Answer (score 0):

One thing that catch my eye is replacing 'this' with 'getContext()'.

Fragments themselves (this) are not a valid context for UI operations, they instead rely on the context of the underlying Activity.

So my guess is that the example you have found was intended to show a list in an Activity and not a fragment.